# Load XML to DataFrame in R

Tags: xml, r, xml-parsing

I am new to R programming and trying to load a simple XML. I tried

```
data <- xmlToDataFrame("temp.xml")
```

but got this error

> Error in xmlToDataFrame(xmlParse(doc), colClasses, homogeneous, collectNames,  : 
>     error in evaluating the argument 'doc' in selecting a method for function 'xmlToDataFrame': Error: XML content does not seem to be XML: 'temp.xml'`

**XML Schema**

```
<root>
  <row Id="1" UserId="1" Name="Rohit" Date="2009-06-29T10:28:58.013" />
  <row Id="2" UserId="3" Name="Rohit" Date="2009-06-29T10:28:58.030" />
</root>
```

Also I tried:

```
xml <- xmlParse("temp.xml")
```

Output:

> Error: XML content does not seem to be XML: 'temp.xml'

My XML file is in same working directory.

Also if you want to try, I have uploaded the sample XML here: http://www4.ncsu.edu/~rkandha/temp.xml
Please provide some direction on which function I should use here.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Updated. Though I have not done anything major yet.

Comment: `as.data.frame(xmlToList(xml))`

Comment: I tried that but it gives result in different format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
text ='<root>
  <row Id="1" UserId="1" Name="Rohit" Date="2009-06-29T10:28:58.013" />
  <row Id="2" UserId="3" Name="Rohit" Date="2009-06-29T10:28:58.030" />
</root>'

library(XML)
do.call(rbind,xmlToList(xmlParse(file=text,asText=TRUE)))
    Id  UserId Name    Date                     
row "1" "1"    "Rohit" "2009-06-29T10:28:58.013"
row "2" "3"    "Rohit" "2009-06-29T10:28:58.030"
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked well. I have additional question on this, how I can select particular columns for the xml. E.g. If I want to load ID and Name only instead of all fields of XML.

Comment: see `?xpathSApply` and read about how to create `xpath` query.